# Manually adapt DbFirst model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have project using EF with a DbFirst model. 
Some properties of an entity need to be adjusted to fit the needs of the project. I did this by editing the .edmx Designer file manually. These adjustments are minor string manupulations.
The problem is: Everytime the model is updated from the database, these changes are overwritten. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what kinds of modifications you're doing on the EDMX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're wanting to do, EF has alot of 'hooks' available to you so you can add custom code, not in the designer.  All the classes are partial, so you can create a partial class, and then hook into the OnYourPropertyNameChanging if want to alter the setter.

Excerpt from some of my code:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String EmployeeComment
{
    get
    {
        return _EmployeeComment;
    }
    set
    {
        OnEmployeeCommentChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("EmployeeComment");
        _EmployeeComment = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
        ReportPropertyChanged("EmployeeComment");
        OnEmployeeCommentChanged();
    }
}
private global::System.String _EmployeeComment;
partial void OnEmployeeCommentChanging(global::System.String value);
partial void OnEmployeeCommentChanged();
```

So, if you wanted to do custom logic in the Changing method you could declare a partial class, and put your code as follows:

```
public partial class Comment
{
  partial OnEmployeeCommentChanging(string value)
  {
     /* your code goes here */
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! I had to use the ...Changed method instead of ...Changing, otherwise the property would get overwritten again. Awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, except doing he modifications from the database so these changes will remain stagnant, otherwise create an event on model update so each time your model is updated, your settings will be reinforced.

Comment: Is it possible to provide custom getter/setter with DataAnnotations or some other way?

Comment: it is possible of course(if you mean some kind of type proxy between the model and your methods), but it will result in spaghetti code and it will be hard to maintain in the future, thats why i suggested an event based solution so its more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

That is right when you update the model from database it gets refreshed. You need to create a seperate class where you can define your entities and you can customize this.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers cover most of what you need.

Your entity models are all built as partial classes.  Each time you do anything to the database you change the class definition.  That is why they all have the header that says DON'T CHANGE THIS CODE!

Assuming you have a data project that your data is in, I create new classes in the same project.  So if your model is

```
partial class Customer:EntityObject
```

Then you would create a CustomerOverload class library that is defined as

```
partial class Customer
```

And that class would then contain your additions etc.  Just don't add methods, those won't carry over to the client.